# Why ORB is not as good as SIFT in matching for these two images?

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction, sift, surf, orb

I tested ORB, SIFT and SURF matchings.

SIFT is the best followed by SURF, then ORB is the last.

But people say ORB is better than SIFT.

In my case I wonder why?
[image]
[image]

Original images are also attached.

[image]
[image]

My code is as follows.

```
int imagematching(Mat &img1, Mat & img2){
    if( !img1.data || !img2.data )
    { 
        std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; 
        return FAILED_IN_LOAD_IMAGES; 
    }
    int max_keypoints = 500;
#if defined(USE_SURF)
    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( max_keypoints );
    Ptr<SURF> extractor = SURF::create();
#elif defined(USE_SIFT)
    Ptr<SIFT> detector = SIFT::create();
    Ptr<SIFT> extractor = SIFT::create();
#elif defined(USE_ORB)
    Ptr<ORB> detector = ORB::create();

#endif
    //--Step 1: Key point detection
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
#if defined(USE_SURF) || defined(USE_SIFT)    
    detector->detect( img1, keypoints1 );
    detector->detect( img2, keypoints2 );   

    extractor->compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    extractor->compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);
#elif defined(USE_ORB)
    Mat dp1, dp2;
    detector->detectAndCompute(img1, Mat(), keypoints1, dp1);
    detector->detectAndCompute(img2, Mat(), keypoints2, dp2);
    if(dp1.type()!=CV_32F) {
       dp1.convertTo(descriptors1, CV_32F);
    }
    if(dp2.type()!=CV_32F) {
       dp2.convertTo(descriptors2, CV_32F);
    }
#endif

#if defined(USE_FLANN)
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

#endif
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);   

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 999999;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++ )
    { 
      double dist = matches[i].distance;
      if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
      if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );
    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++ )
    { 
      if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
         { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
    }
    matches.clear();

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches( img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2,
               good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

    descriptors1.release();
    descriptors2.release();

    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> first_keypoints;
    std::vector<Point2f> second_keypoints;

    for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
    {
       //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
       first_keypoints.push_back( keypoints1[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
       second_keypoints.push_back( keypoints2[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
    }
    keypoints1.clear();
    keypoints2.clear();
    good_matches.clear();
    Mat H = findHomography( first_keypoints, second_keypoints, CV_RANSAC );

    first_keypoints.clear();
    second_keypoints.clear();

    //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    std::vector<Point2f> first_image_corners(4);
    first_image_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); first_image_corners[1] = cvPoint( img1.cols, 0 );
    first_image_corners[2] = cvPoint( img1.cols, img1.rows ); first_image_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, img1.rows );
    std::vector<Point2f> second_image_corners(4);

    perspectiveTransform( first_image_corners, second_image_corners, H);

    //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
    line( img_matches, second_image_corners[0] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), second_image_corners[1] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
    line( img_matches, second_image_corners[1] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), second_image_corners[2] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
    line( img_matches, second_image_corners[2] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), second_image_corners[3] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
    line( img_matches, second_image_corners[3] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), second_image_corners[0] + Point2f( img1.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );

    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow( "ORB Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches );

    waitKey(0);
    img_matches.release();
    first_image_corners.clear();
    second_image_corners.clear();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Any problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: *But people say ORB is better than SIFT.* This is a very unscientific statement. Source? If someone claims that something is better, usually they give comparative studies/reasoning. Else, that statement is worthless! If SIFT works better for you, work with that I guess.

Comment: Y true. But I want to use ORB than SIFT. In these two images, SIFT is better. That is why I am surprised. I'll look into it. Just want to hear what other say.

Comment: So, you want an oppinion based answer? :P You know thats off-topic

Comment: Not opinion,some people have experience on it. They may want to share. Isn't it good?

Comment: In my experience, sift are the best in general. For some specific cases there may be something better, but they never perform badly. Remember that binary descriptors as ORB carry less information than non-binary ones, and so there's no surprise if they are worse. Also, I'm pretty sure MSER works really good in this case. Oh, seems opinion-based to me too....

Comment: :) thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Binary descriptors are more efficient in feature matching and take-up less memory. So there is a trade off between efficiency and precision in detection.

Here's a paper that compared ORB and SIFT: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865516303300
It says that ORB is two orders of magnitude faster than SIFT but the tradeoff was that was that the authors found ORB to be more sensitive to noise.